# Overloaded operator -= in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have defined an overload for operator -= for my Rational-class:

```
rational.hh:
class Rational {

public:
    Rational(int numerator, int denominator) : numerator(numerator), denominator(denominator)
    { }

    int getNumerator() const;
    int getDenominator() const;
    Rational& operator-=(const Rational& bar);

private:
    int numerator, denominator;

rational.cc:
Rational& Rational::operator-=(const Rational& subtracted) {
    Rational result((*this).getNumerator()*subtracted.getDenominator() - (*this).getDenominator()*subtracted.getNumerator(), (*this).getDenominator()*subtracted.getDenominator());
    return *this;
}
```

The code compiles without warnings but this piece of code does not change the value of r:

```
  Rational r(1, 1);
  r -= Rational(1, 2);
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You're never changing `this`. You're just creating a new object and then returning `*this`.

Comment: A tip: those `(*this).`s in the calculation of `result` aren't needed, and they just make it harder to read. That's not the cause of the problem, though. Add `*this = result;` before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-=` operator should be changing the values of `numerator` and `denominator`, but it does not. Add code to set these values into `this`, instead of creating `result`:

```
Rational& Rational::operator-=(const Rational& subtracted) {
    numerator = (*this).getNumerator()*subtracted.getDenominator() - (*this).getDenominator()*subtracted.getNumerator();
    denominator = (*this).getDenominator()*subtracted.getDenominator();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I can now see my mistake, but still, when I do as you suggest, I get no change in the Rational object's values - I think I should declare "friend Rational& operator-=(const Rational& bar)" in the header file, but then I get an error "Overloaded 'operator-=' must be a binary operator". I'm confused...

Comment: @rize That is very strange: since you do the assignments in the `-=` operator, the changes should stick. Try this in a debugger, and check that you are not subtracting `0/1` by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You never assign to "this" in your operator-=!

Your function creates a temporary Rational object (called "result").  Then, it forgets about "result" and returns this.

You need to actually assign to this->numerator and this->denominator.

Answer (score 1):

It is so, because you did not change the object.

You must change object member variable instead of creating temporary object.

```
Rational& Rational::operator-=(const Rational& subtracted) {
    numerator = ...;
    denominator = ...;
    return *this;
}
```

You should know that this:

```
Rational result(...);
```

just creates local object. It has nothing to do with object for which the `-=` is called.

Comment: I see my mistake clearly now, but even writing as you suggest, I get no change in the Rational object. Should I declare the operator starting with "friend" in the header file, to have access to the private variables numerator and denominator? But then I get another error, see comment above...

Comment: @rize Your operator is part of the class, so it can already access all private values.

Comment: Okey, now I got it working, so I understand the declarations better. Thank you!